# Em ordem decrescente, retire um valor do número inserido até 0

Tags: java, for

Preciso que o programa retire um valor do número inserido pelo usuário até atingir o valor 0.
Não sei se o laço de repetição utilizado deve ser o for, mas meu programa ficou assim.

```
package numerodescrecente;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumeroDescrecente {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("DIGITE UM NUMERO");
        int n1 = leitor.nextInt();
        for (n1=n1;n1>0;n1--)
        {
            System.out.println("Numero: "+n1);
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Se você deseja incluir o `0`, você deve alterar a condição `n1>0` para `n1>=0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu programa funciona. [**Veja ele funcionando no ideone.**](https://ideone.com/v6aZ1g) Com a entrada 12, ele produz essa saída:

```
DIGITE UM NUMERO
Numero: 12
Numero: 11
Numero: 10
Numero: 9
Numero: 8
Numero: 7
Numero: 6
Numero: 5
Numero: 4
Numero: 3
Numero: 2
Numero: 1
```

Apesar disso, há algumas coisas a se rever no seu código:

- `n1=n1` não faz absolutamente nada. É melhor colocar o `int n1 = leitor.nextInt()` como a instrução de inicialização do `for`.
- Se a ideia é ir até o 0, use `n1 >= 0`.

Seu código deve ficar assim:

```
package numerodescrecente;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class NumeroDescrecente {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner leitor = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("DIGITE UM NÚMERO");
        for (int n1 = leitor.nextInt(); n1 >= 0; n1--) {
            System.out.println("Número: " + n1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação. Abraços.